# Having a hard time installing Julia (IJulia + Python)

Tags: python, julia

I am struggling with installing "IJulia" in Julia. I tried `Pkg.add("IJulia")` and `.build("IJulia")`
but there must be some problem going on with this part it keeps saying

> "LoadError: Failed to precompile Parsers
>   [69de0a69-1ddd-5017-9359-2bf0b02dc9f0] to
>   C:\Users\박원정.julia\compiled\v1.4\Parsers\833b9_AFua3.ji."

It would be much appreciated if someone can help me with resolving this problem...

[image]

Comment: always put result as text, not image.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I will follow your advice from now on.

Comment: I think you have corrupt precompile cache. You can try to delete `.julia/compiled` and retry.

Answer (score 1):

On the first run IJulia is installing Jupyter. Having bad luck this might fail. 
Once you perform the already suggested deleting `.julia\compiled`,  you can try installing Jupyter into your Julia manually (this is something I do when providing Jupyter installation instructions for large groups of people and is tested to work each time on many machines and environments):

```
using Pkg
pkg"add Conda"
using Conda
Conda.runconda(`install jupyter --yes`)
pkg"add IJulia"
pkg"precompile"
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. One more thing to go over though, I've been using Jupyter notebook for couple of months and is that means I have to delete it and install again through the Julia while installing IJulia? Lastly, when do I have enter that codes you mentioned above ?

Comment: Sometime Julia package repository gets stalled. One reason for this could be that packages used to download many files and place them in different location (now it has been finally solved by introduction of package artifacts). Hence sometime the easiest thing was to dump the intire `.julia` folder and install from scratch. Fortunatelly, this is happening less and less often. Regarding my commands - this is just a Julia code and you copy paste it to the Julia REPL console.